# Name of type pattern: R a b = Q (a -> (R a b,b))

Tags: haskell, data-structures, types, terminology

I am looking for some vocabulary here.  There are a number of shapes that have common names.  For example `L a = Empty | Cons a L` Is generally called a "list," while `T a = Leaf a | Node  (T a) (T a)` is a "binary tree"  and `St s a :: St (s->(a,s))` is the form of the State Monad.

I would like to know if a shape like this has a name:

```
data  R a b = Q (a -> (R a b,b))
```

I've seen this pattern in Arrow frameworks and State Machine implementations. The recursive function makes it feel a little like a State Monad or a Cont Monad. It is also the only structure besides `(->)` and `(>=>)` for which I have seen an instance of Arrow defined.

Is there a common name for this data structure?

Comment: You've got a bonsai tree there :). A better binary tree is `T a = Branch (T a) (T a) | Leaf a`

Comment: @JohnF.Miller wouldn't you want to store some `a` somewhere in that `T a`? :D (sorry... I had to...) (or maybe it's a phantom type!? :p)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is an [*automaton arrow*](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/arrows/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow-Transformer-Automaton.html), also known as a Mealy machine. Your specific example just uses `(->)` as the underlying arrow; another common choice is `Kleisli m` for some monad *m* (which just turns `a -> b` into `a -> m b`; for example, `data R a b = Q (a -> MyMonad (b, R a b))`).

It's commonly used in [functional reactive programming](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_Reactive_Programming) (specifically, arrowised FRP — see, e.g. [netwire](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire) and these two blog posts: [1](https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2012/2012-01-08-streams-coroutines.md), [2](https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2012/2012-01-17-declarative-game-logic-afrp.md)), and has applications to general stream processing (like iteratees).

It's similar to a coroutine in many ways, but it's a more specific concept. The two blog posts I linked call them coroutines, so "coroutine" is certainly a common way to refer to it, but the precise name is an automaton arrow.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and more.  Thank you for the very complete answer.

Answer (score 8):

I would call that data structure a Coroutine.

It expresses a computation that can be controlled in parallel to some other computation, and that can be evaluated step-wise. While the interface you present isn't the exact interface that is used for the class of Coroutines in Haskell (A more general Coroutine is also monad-agnostic, meaning that the wrapped function returns a `m (R a b, b)`, and coroutines do not have to consume input, while you here always have to feed the computation with an `a`), it is similar enough.

The data structure also represents a subset of what is called Comonads.

Answer (score 3):

That type looks related to the type I would expect to use for a *transducer* -- I would only expect that the output type be monoidal. Wikipedia has a page on a particular class of transducer, the [finite state transducers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer), that should be a good launching point for a literature search.